# PIP Install Cannot Find Header File - How to Locate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pycharm, sdl

I'm trying to pip install [a library](https://matham.github.io/ffpyplayer/installation.html#compiling) that needs access to an external header files (i.e. SDL). I know this because I get the following error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SDL_version.h': No such file or directory
```

[The installation guide](https://matham.github.io/ffpyplayer/installation.html#compiling) says to set SDL_ROOT to the root of the library's directory --- i.e. the place where all the header/dll files are. I tried to do this by (i) creating an environmental variable in windows...

[image: env vars windows attempt]

.. and programmatically setting it in Python.

[image]

And the bloody thing still won't work. I get the same error --- pip install cannot locate the header files.

What am I doing wrong? How do I tell pip where to locate these files?

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit OS, Python 3.11, and PyCharm 2022.2.2 (Community Edition)

Comment: That library [has precompiled wheels for Python 3.10](https://pypi.org/project/ffpyplayer/4.3.5/#files). If you're willing to downgrade to Python 3.10 for now, you don't need to faff around with compiling anything.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to define the variable locally in PowerShell...

```
Set-Variable -Name "SDL_ROOT" -Value "C:\\Program Files\\Python311\\external_lib\\SDL2-2.24.2"
```

and THEN, only after the variables were defined locally could I do a pip install.

```
pip install ffpyplayer
```